# Ubuntu 12.04 printing problem on Lexmark x340

Tags: printing

After upgrading from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, I have printing issues with **Lexmark x340** :

Printing from **Libre Office** or a pdf file: if the document is more complex (longer than 2 pages), the first page is printed correctly, followed by several of pages with some hieroglyphics. This can only be stopped by switching the printer off and then on again.

In case of simple documents, the first print usually comes out OK. Then, if another print is requested, the story begins again: unwanted characters, on many pages.

To overcome this problem, I now do the following: print a document, switch the printer off and back on, print again, and so on...

Does anyone has a fix?

Comment: many thanks its working whit x340 all the best

Answer (score 1):

After several months of having problems with printers, because we migrated from Windows to  Linux in our company which have more than 200 computers... now we found the driver which works on all our printers. The driver is **ljet4** , just found some similar model of printer with **ljet4** sufix on name and it will work. I wrote more on my blog : http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2013/01/driver-that-works-on-allmost-all.html

We didn't try on your model but every similar model we have worked very well.

Comment: Works great on Lexmark E360d. I also got a problem, that the printer printed just one line of always the same garbage (not every time, but in 8 of 10 print requests). Thank you a lot! That was a really annoying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem with Lexmark x350d and troubles disappeared when I used:
`Generic PCL 4 LF Printer - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.10-pre2` (note: generate a new  configuration from a chosen generic file PPL) from generic Ubuntu 14.04 core.

my configuration:

```
trays: tray 1
duples: installed
flash: not installed
printer memory: 32MB
```

`usb://Lexmark/E350d?serial=6232T1N`. It also works for me with Lexmark e350 and oki b430d.